# Hide the "describe what you've tried" bullet (new askers' modal)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users

Our new asker's modal has the three bullets:

> 1. Summarize the problem
> 2. Provide details and any research
> 3. When appropriate, describe what you've tried

We are able to [remove the third bullet point](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/377061/313677) (see "*Short version …*" section at the end of that answer).  I'd like to propose that we do that.

There are arguments for and against, so it's important that we have a frank discussion to reach consensus on whether that's what we want as a community.

Comment: That list is perfect for SO, really doesn't work for CR. There should be no `problem` in the code on CR.

Comment: I've made this change as of 6 July 2022.

Answer (score 23):

## Yes.

This statement implies that if you've tried and failed, then you can post your non-working attempt on CR.

We should remove that instruction.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than just "Summarize the problem", how about "Summarize the problem the code solves"?

Comment: That would be nice, but it's not listed as one of the site-specific changes that are provided (see the linked Meta.SE question).

Comment: It might be worth proposing this anyway.  Even if it can't currently be done, perhaps this will encourage them to make it possible.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes - and also.

Remove the third bullet, and add a sentence elsewhere in the modal encouraging askers to summarise the "paths not taken".

Answer (score -6):

## No.

Describing the approaches not used can be useful, particularly in performance questions.

We should keep asking posters to describe what else they have tried.